# How to copy all files to new directory using bash commands in yml files?

Tags: bash, cpanel, git-bash

I want to deploy my git repository in cpanel. As far as I know to do that I need .cpanel.yml file with several commands in it. My file:

```
---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/ygolokru/public_html/testForsite/
    - /bin/cp * $DEPLOYPATH
```

However it appeares that it only copies files in the main folder:
For example, I have this file structure:

- css

  - style.css
- index.html

It will only copy index.html, but I want it to copy all directory. What should I do for that?

Answer (score 0):

cp -ird $SRCDIR $DEPLOYPATH
If you want to run in a batch mode and overwritten files are not any concern 
cp -frd $SRCDIR $DEPLOYPATH

Answer (score 0):

Just change to

> ```
> - /bin/cp -fr * $DEPLOYPATH
> ```

This will check subfolders recursively